# Kafka - SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator

Tags: apache-kafka

I connect my app to Kafka through SASL_SSL using keytab. At first it worked well, but once it got an error. How to fix this and avoid such errors in future? stacktrace is bellow.

```
java.io.IOException: Channel could not be created for socket java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[closed]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:280)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$700(NetworkClient.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1035)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:920)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:508)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:289)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: Failed to configure SaslClientAuthenticator
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Principal could not be determined from Subject, this may be a transient failure due to Kerberos re-login
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.firstPrincipal(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.<init>(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:135)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildClientAuthenticator(SaslChannelBuilder.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.buildChannel(SaslChannelBuilder.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.buildAndAttachKafkaChannel(Selector.java:289)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.registerChannel(Selector.java:280)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.connect(Selector.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:864)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.access$700(NetworkClient.java:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:1035)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.maybeUpdate(NetworkClient.java:920)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:508)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: `this may be a transient failure due to Kerberos re-login` - did you try re-running it? If not, can you give more details of how this is configured, what your source application is, etc

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Thanks, a restart of the app solved the problem. :)